# Create superflat map in Minecraft with trees, grass, etc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of the latest Minecraft snapshot (12W40A), it is now possible to create superflat worlds with structures such as trees and grass. I still haven't found out how to create a superflat world with this setting - where is the option for this?

Comment: Not only with that; abandoned mines too. Truly, a massive mine located entirely above the surface of the world is a sight to behold!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add structures such as trees and grass (and others) using the Customize interface. As of 12W40A, you have to use *More World Options...*. From there, set the *World Type* to *Superflat*, then click *Customize* and then *Presets*. You'll be presented with a box that lets you share presets. The format for these presets [can be found on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Superflat#Preset_code_format).

To create a superflat world that also generates trees, flowers, and tall grass, use the following preset:

```
2;7,2x3,2;3;decoration
```

This will generate a world with a layer of bedrock, two layers of dirt above that, and then one layer of grass above that. Trees, flowers, tall grass, and so on will be generated. The trees will be fairly spaced apart.

Note that villages *cannot* be generated here, since they only generate in *plains* or *desert* biomes, and the *Extreme Hills* biome used to add the trees, flowers, and tall grass does not allow villages to spawn.

However, structures such as Abandoned Mineshafts and Strongholds can still be generated. Simply add `,mineshaft`, `,stronghold`, `,dungeon`, etc. at the end of the preset. There are various parameters that can be added, such as `,mineshaft(chance=0.1)`. These parameters are detailed in the wiki.

If you want more trees, you can change the `3` to a `4` to use the *Forest* biome. This will generate trees far more densely.

Comment: @DECGWP hm? I already put in a link, unless you're talking about a different article. It's quite possible that a new, more relevant article has been written; I haven't really kept up with Minecraft.

Comment: Nevermind, my iphone must have not properly loaded the link, thanks for clearing that up!